# Weird animation of a Button in Stack Views in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

I created a `SampleView` where a `Button` is wrapped in a `ZStack`, and the whole `ZStack` is animated on tap of the `Button`. It looks like below:

[image]

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
    @State private var toggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                toggle.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap here to move!")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .black))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: toggle ? 0 : 200)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: toggle)
    }
}

struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // ZStack {
            SampleView()
        // }
    }
}
```

There's a bunch of other views that I want to present, so I simply wrapped `SampleView` inside a `VStack` (or `ZStack`). **Now, the animation started to break**:

[image]

```swift
struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            SampleView()
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that I can work around this behavior by wrapping the button action with `withAnimation`.

```swift
withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
    toggle.toggle()
}
```

Still, I wonder what's going on here. Is this a bug?

Comment: May be it won’t work but did you tried to have a var  for y offset that you update when you toggle toggle  and make animation on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly looks like a bug.  The `Text` label of the button is not getting the `.animation()` value applied to it, but the background is.

Here is another way to fix it.  Apply the `.animation()` modifier to the `Text` label as well:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    @State private var toggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                toggle.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap here to move!")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .black))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: toggle) // here
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: toggle ? 0 : 200)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: toggle)
    }
}
```

---

**More Evidence of the Bug**

In this example, we have two buttons in a `VStack` that move together.  This works correctly in iOS 15.5, but it breaks in iOS 16. The animation breaks for the button that is being pressed, but it works for the other button.

[image: Showing bug in simulator]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var toggle: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                toggle.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap here to move!")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .black))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)

            Button {
                toggle.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap here to move!")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .black))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.blue)

        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: toggle ? 0 : 200)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: toggle)
    }
}
```

The same fixes apply here: add the `.animation()` modifier to the `Text` label of each button, or wrap the button action with  `withAnimation { }`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug too. I found a temporary workaround.

You can try `onTapGesture`.

I fixed the weird animation.

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
    @State private var toggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
//            Button {
//                toggle.toggle()
//            } label: {
                Text("Tap here to move!")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .black))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
//            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                toggle.toggle()
            }
        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: toggle ? 0 : 200)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: toggle)
    }
}

struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
         ZStack {
            SampleView()
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding withAnimation around the toggle the issue is fixed.
On iOS 15 this was not needed. I checked iOS 17 (in Xcode15 Beta6) and it behaves like iOS 16. So it seems we need to fix this on our side.

```
struct SampleView: View {
    @State private var toggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                   toggle.toggle()
               }
            } label: {
                Text("Tap here to move!")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .black))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: toggle ? 0 : 200)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: toggle)
    }
}

struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
          SampleView()
        }
    }
}
```